# XML Rotation not working

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to rotate a textview by 360 degrees . But the rotation isn't happening . I have seen many examples but nothing worked .

My rot.xml file is

```
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="400"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
```

and MainActivity.java

```
tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
//this.context = context;
rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rot);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        tv.setAnimation(rotate);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why is duration `0`?

Comment: rotate by **360** degrees with no duration? what do you expect with such rotation?

Comment: I tried to rotate by 90 degrees also but it didn't work

Comment: use `startAnimation`, not `setAnimation`

Comment: It worked ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duration? Why `0`?

```
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="400"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
/>
```

And, Use `tv.startAnimation(rotate);`

**Reference** - [setAnimation(Animation animation)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation))

Sets the next animation to play for this view. If you want the animation to play immediately, use `startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)` instead.